# Glide does not rotate image in right orientation

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, android-glide

I creating a custom camera application in which after taking the photo I am setting the bitmap in the imageview. I am using the library known as **GLIDE**. To rotate image in the right direction I am getting the Exif information from Input stream.

Once I take the portrait photo the **onPictureTaken** returns the byte[]. After checking the byte[] the Exif tag returned is                                 **ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL** which means the rotation of image is normal and it does not need any more rotation. However, the image set by the Glide in the image view is in landscape instead of portrait and it requires rotation of 90 degree .May be there is something  in the glide library that rotates the image automatically. Does someone has any idea?

Any help is appreciated. The code is given below:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
 Glide.with(this)
                .load(data)
                .asBitmap().override(height, width) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                        try {
                            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                            Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(is);
                            final ExifIFD0Directory exifIFD0Directory = metadata.getFirstDirectoryOfType(ExifIFD0Directory.class);
                            Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                            int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                            int h = bitmap.getHeight();

                            if (exifIFD0Directory.containsTag(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_ORIENTATION)) {
                                final int exifOrientation = exifIFD0Directory.getInt(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_ORIENTATION); //checking Exif here it returns image is normal
                                switch (exifOrientation) {
                                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:

                                        break;
                                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                                        mtx.postRotate(90);
                                        break;
                                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                                        mtx.postRotate(180);
                                        break;

                                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                                        mtx.postRotate(270);
                                        break;
                                }
                            }

                            photo = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);

                            Imageview.setImageBitmap(photo);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                });
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @DarkLeonart try this library before uploading to the server, https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor, I was getting same rotation problem basically on high-end devices but if, before uploading, I am compressing, then the issue is resolved.